# Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.0.4 to Ubuntu 22.04.1 and facing issue in apt update

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I upgraded my system from ubuntu-20.0.4 to ubuntu-22.04.1, and I am facing one warning while I run the command of

```
sudo apt update
```

The warning is

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cory-tgl/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cory-tgl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I checked my source list and it doesn't contain "somerville-cory-tgl" at all. My source.list file is following

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

(Edit)
However, I did found the text `somerville-cory-tgl` in different file named `oem-somerville-cory-tgl-meta.list` in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

The text looks like

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-cory-tgl
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-cory-tgl
```

If I comment `deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-cory-tgl` line then it fixes the issue but I am not sure how important this line is since there is something I can see in `http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/somerville/`. It might be important.

what should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you check all the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory?

Comment: @user535733 Oh yes I found where `somerville-cory-tgl` is. It is in file `oem-somerville-cory-tgl-meta.list`

the whole file has text as



`deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-cory-tgl
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-cory-tgl`

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: @user535733 I updated the post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a step back and let's find out **why there's an OEM archive**. You need to know this in order to understand the answer.

Some OEMs, including Dell, send their equipment to a Canonical team in Taiwan for hardware testing, and for assistance with new hardware Linux compatibility. (This is also the source of [Ubuntu Certified](https://ubuntu.com/certified) hardware)

That compatibility software works its way upstream into the Linux kernel over a year or two, but while it's doing that Ubuntu users need that OEM repo so their new hardware will work. **When the generic Linux kernel includes that compatibility, the OEM repo is no longer required.**

Now for the answer:

Two years ago, your hardware needed that OEM repository for your hardware. But that's no longer the case, the generic Linux kernel should work properly on your hardware, and that particular pocket has been discontinued.

That's why you are getting the warnings: Apt is telling you that the repo has been discontinued. (Apt does not know why)

Simply disable (comment out) the `somerville-cory-tgl` line.

Since you have received no warnings for the `somerville` line, leave it active.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the reason from above.

I met the problem in the Dell Machine.

In order to disable somerville-*, you could

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm oem-*
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).